# Is the adj. "individual-traveler-friendly" correct？

Tags: adjectives, hyphens

When I was writing an essay, I wanted to write that traveling without a tour guide is friendly to individual travelers because it conduces to a flexible schedule. A phrase "dog-friendly hotel" came into my mind, so I wondered if I can write "individual-traveler-friendly".

Comment: Can you provide a full sentence? As an adjective, it's a bit awkward but might be OK in some contexts.

Comment: Every person (whether traveling or not) is an individual, so I'd prefer [***solo traveler-friendly***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solo-traveler-friendly%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=bkv:p&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUvYrpj__-AhVDolwKHTg8B2AQpwV6BAgBEBU&biw=1280&bih=635&dpr=3) (which occurs at least once in Google Books, whereas ***individual** traveler-friendly* isn't recorded at all).

Comment: [...here's another example](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solo-traveller-friendly%22&biw=1280&bih=635&tbs=bkv%3Ap&tbm=bks&ei=XzxmZJ3MI9iqgAajxaTQBQ&ved=0ahUKEwjd9-X1j__-AhVYFcAKHaMiCVoQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22solo-traveller-friendly%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ6AZY6AZgiQpoAHAAeACAAfEBiAGNA5IBBTAuMS4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) with the older British spelling ***traveller***. I think it's up to you whether to use one hyphen or two.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'traveller' is still the correct spelling in British English.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I meant *the older **spelling** (which is **British**)*. But when my browser spell-checker objects to British spelling I often just accept its advice for the sake of a quiet life. (You can't fight City Hall or US cultural imperialism! :)

Comment: The full sentence may be "traveling without a tour guide is individual-traveler-friendly because it allows for personal freedom. Individual travelers can easily make changes to the traveler itineraries and choose to stay in certain places than otherwise possible."

Answer (score 1):

The construction *XXXX-friendly* is a "productive" format, suitable for a wide range of XXXX.

But every person (whether traveling or not) is an *individual*, so I'd prefer [***solo** traveler-friendly*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solo-traveler-friendly%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=bkv:p&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUvYrpj__-AhVDolwKHTg8B2AQpwV6BAgBEBU&biw=1280&bih=635&dpr=3). And at least that's indexed by Google Books, whereas ***individual** traveler-friendly* isn't recorded at all. And [here's another example](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solo-traveller-friendly%22&biw=1280&bih=635&tbs=bkv%3Ap&tbm=bks&ei=XzxmZJ3MI9iqgAajxaTQBQ&ved=0ahUKEwjd9-X1j__-AhVYFcAKHaMiCVoQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22solo-traveller-friendly%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ6AZY6AZgiQpoAHAAeACAAfEBiAGNA5IBBTAuMS4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) with the British spelling ***traveller***.

I think it's up to you whether to use one hyphen or two (my examples above feature both orthographies).

Answer (score -1):

No, while "friendly to individual travellers" and "individual-traveller-friendly" are valid English phrases, they don't apply in your context.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/friendly):

> **friendly** *adjective*
> **3 b**
> : designed or intended to accommodate particular needs, users, etc.

The term "dog-friendly" means that the hotel is accepting of and willing to cater to travellers with dogs.

It's incorrect to say that travelling without a tour guide is designed or intended to accommodate the particular needs of individual travellers.

You're describing something like "practical" or "convenient" or "well-suited" to individual travellers, rather than "friendly" to them. A mode of travel, itself, cannot be "friendly".

Comment: Why the downvotes? please comment

Comment: It was my downvote. You seem to be saying *individual-traveler-friendly* is inherently invalid, but so far as I'm concerned it's just a somewhat "less natural" alternative to *solo traveler-friendly* (which per my comments under the question, I found written instances of in both BrE and AmE sources). The construction "XXXX-friendly" is "productive" for neologisms, and can be used with a wide range of terms for XXXX.

Comment: Thank you for your answer！I was to write an essay to support my point that traveling without tour guide has its advantage. If I cannot use the adj. "individual-traveler-friendly", which word should I chose to summarize it when I provide details like traveling without tour guide allows for personal freedom like changing travel itinerary.

Comment: The problem actually is whether the pattern "adj.+adj.+n." is correct. I am not very proficient in English so I might confuse individual and solo, I will check which is better for my original text.

Comment: If the pattern "adj.+adj.+n" can be used, I think I can create a new adj. and other people can understand my meaning even if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't mean that "*individual-traveller-friendly*" is completely invalid English. I mean the phrase cannot apply to "travelling without a tour guide". The examples I found of "solo-traveler friendly" include, "*Iceland is extremely well known for being solo-traveler friendly*", which makes sense because it means Iceland itself is accommodating to solo travellers. My answer states that you cannot apply that phrase to the general concept of travelling without a guide, as travelling without a guide, itself isn't accommodating, so the OP's proposed sentence is nonsense.

Comment: @gotube: I don't understand that. The OP has used ***individual*** where ***solo*** is somewhat more idiomatic - in a context where ***single, unaccompanied*** and doubtless other terms could be used instead, all with exactly the same meaning being both intended and understood. In which context I should say that it wouldn't have occurred to me to think that someone travelling solo is travelling without a ***guide***. The obvious most likely interpretation is we're talking about someone travelling ***alone, with no travelling companions***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not quibbling either about "solo" vs "individual" nor does my answer relate to the meaning of the sentence. My only assertion here is that phrases with "X-friendly", such as "dog-friendly", "wheelchair-friendly" and "individual-traveller-friendly" can only apply to people and institutions that have the capacity for making accommodations for others. The concept of travelling without a guide, itself, cannot make accommodations, so it's an invalid target for "X-friendly" phrases. I've clarified my answer

Comment: I know OP mentioned "travelling without a tour guide" as a possible target for his "XXXX-traveller-friendly", but I still don't see that's directly relevant to the question (is "XXXX-traveller-friendly" a valid construction? And if so, for what values of XXXX?). I'm perfectly happy with, say, *A day excursion on one of our chartered coaches is a solo-traveller-friendly experience* - the only reason I'm less keen on *Travelling on our chartered coaches is solo-traveller-friendly* is because of the clumsy repetition. I see no semantic issue there, with or without guides.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The way I read the OP's question, the OP never asked about "for what values of XXXX", only whether that one phrase was correct in that one context. I only answered that question, but have since expanded my answer for clarity. My first revision introduced errors, but I think it's correct now